# Can you run Android MediaPlayer from JavaScript using Cordova 2.9.0 to play audio devices?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, audio, cordova

I have created an app using JavaScript, HTML, CSS and Cordova 2.9.0 which outputs a sound when objects are dragged on the screen. It works fine on iOS, but I am struggling to get the sound to output in the emulator.

I have looked at many other posts and the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html), it says to use the MediaPlayer to output audio files. I am not using Java though so cant use the code they have shown.

Does anyone know how to run the MediaPlayer through JavaScript to play the audio files?

Here is what I have so far (works in Chrome and on iOS):

```
$(function() {
$(".cards img").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        if(window.HTMLAudioElement) {
            console.log(ui.helper.context.id);
            var id = ui.helper.context.id;
            console.log("playing sound ", id);
            var soundFile = '../assets/audio/' + id + ".mp3";
            var snd = new Media(soundFile);
            snd.play();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
});
});
```

Here are the errors that get output when I drag the images:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2011/05/using-media-class-in-phonegap.html).

For some reason `var soundFile = '../assets/audio/' + id + ".mp3";` doesn't work and `var soundFile = '/android_asset/www/assets/audio/' + id + ".mp3";` does..

Anyone know why it works with iOS Cordova, but not Android?